# Mandatory languages for privacy policies in Japan (APPI)

Tags: gdpr, japan

I work on Apps, currently Android, which are distributed via Google Play.

As the EU has GDPR, in Japan they have APPI (Act on the Protection of Personal Information) which is something like the Japanese version of GDPR. I read at several places that it is required that the GDPR is always available in the country's own language which requires a lot of translations for the EU. However, I cannot find information if APPI is mandatory in Japanese or if English is sufficient.

I assume it is mandatory, but I would like to have a confirmation and/or a link to the according rules.

Comment: I changed it now to a single question.

Comment: Thanks, looks good to me!

Comment: @compenthusiast: The link is an interesting overview, but I could not find any mentioning of Japan.